# iTextSharp latex to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, latex

I would like to know that does iTextSharp has ability to conver Latex to PDF or generate PDF using Latex. If it has so could you please provide me sample code, or link to the tutorial.

Thank you,

Comment: if you have a latex file (`.tex`) and want  to convert to PDF, download https://miktex.org/download this probably easiest way.

Comment: The best tool to convert LaTeX to PDF, is LaTeX. Miktex, mentioned in the comment above, is one possible implementation. Check the LaTeX website for others.

Comment: Hello, I want some API to be used in C#,which will be able to create pdf on the fly from latex.